# How to calculate job target in hex

Tags: mining, mining-pools, proof-of-work, difficulty, pool-mining

I received a mining job with `target = f3220000`.

My XMRig miner logged the following statement:

```
new job from ... diff 480045 algo rx/0 height 2027084
```

I want to find answers to the following questions:

1. How to get a decimal value of difficulty (`480045`) by a hexadecimal
   value of a given target in hex (`f3220000`) ?
2. How to get a hexadecimal value of target (`f3220000`) by a decimal
       value of a given difficulty (`480045`)?

My research led to the following formula:
`target = targetmax / diff` when `targetmax = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`

I also found the something in the source of some pools [here](https://github.com/sammy007/monero-stratum/blob/master/util/util.go#L24) and [here](https://github.com/Snipa22/nodejs-pool/blob/master/lib/pool.js#L460). They have a different logic and I can’t understand it anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. How to get a decimal value of difficulty (480045) by a hexadecimal value of a given target in hex (f3220000) ?

Swap endian `f3220000` and remove padding gets `22f3`, then `0x100000001 / 0x22f3` yields: `480045`.

> 2. How to get a hexadecimal value of target (f3220000) by a decimal value of a given difficulty (480045)?

`((2^256-1) / 480045) >> 224` is decimal `8947`, hex `0x22f3`. Swap endian and pad yields: `f3220000`.

The reason for both the division in #1 and shift in #2 is because we are exploiting the fact that we are working with only a 32 bit difficulty target. Thus, we are only concerning ourselves with the most significant 32 bits of a 256 bit number.

It's worth noting that this calculation is just legacy hangover of how the pools and miners were doing this when forked, which nobody felt strongly enough to improve upon. The current *miner* implementations foresaw this 32 bit limitation and do have code to handle larger targets [[ref](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/blob/77eb79ced5f260c42d86cc3dc26caee1dbee5ea7/src/base/net/stratum/Job.cpp#L99)], though most pools do not, as can be seen by the pools you cite. In retrospect, it would probably be more sensible if the pools and miners calculated/checked difficulty more akin to how Monero [does](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/9bd0983d5eee1f422bad4d920ab78c70c8e6faeb/src/cryptonote_basic/difficulty.cpp#L105) (i.e. if hash *multiplied by* difficulty doesn't overflow, it's good), as whilst this would mean passing around a slightly larger target in the stratum job message, it's more future-proof.

Comment: Thank's a lot! Swap endian is not very obvious. Can you can add a little more detailed answer?  Or give resources that will help me? I would be very grateful!

Comment: And ">> 224" is not very obvious too =(

Comment: Max diff is 2^256-1 and we are only working with a 32 bit difficulty target. Hence `>>224` is shifting out the bottom 224 bits from our division of the base diff to take only the top 32 bits.

Comment: "Swap endian is not very obvious. Can you can add a little more detailed answer?" <-  You want to know how to swap endian?

Comment: No, I know what is "swap endian". My question is why operation "swap endian" is applied in this case.

Comment: Why someone decided to use BE byte order vs LE in the stratum message is really not relevant. It *is* in that byte order so you need to swap.

Comment: Difficulty = 200000. `((2^256-1) / 200000) >> 224` is decimal `21474`, hex `0x53e2`. Swap endian and pad yields: `e2530000`.

Comment: Target = e2530000. Swap endian `53e20000` and remove padding gets `53e2`, then `0x100000001 / 0x53e2` yields: `200007`. Its should be `200000`. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are just witnessing rounding at play. E.g.`0x100000001 / 200000 = 21474.836485` is a float, and the reverse calc/truncation (with the shift), is using integers, thus you won't *always* get an *exact* match both ways.

Comment: So I can not send the work to the miner with the difficulty of `200000`? I think I mined on `pool.supportxmr.com:3333` and got this kind of work with difficulty of `200000`

Comment: Pools send jobs to miners, which work and then send the result (a hash) back to the pool. If a pool asks you (miner) to meet a target of 0x53e2, the top 32 bits of your hash (256 bit number), need to be less than 0x30d47 (200007).

Comment: Several days ago output of xmrig showed me the job with the difficulty of `200000`. Then what target was sent to me? Or is it impossible?

Comment: If XMRig *prints* a diff of `200000` then the pool sent a target of `0x53e2` (so in the stratum message format `e2530000`). As already mentioned, because there is rounding at play in the calculations above, you wont always get exact matches in both directions of the calculations - e.g. if the jobs target was 1 bigger (0x53e**3**), that would be difficulty 199998.

Comment: Sorry, I'm now trying to convert current mainnet difficult `147640361901` to target (hex) `((2**256-1) // 147640361901) >> 224` and got  `00000000`. Why I have all zeros if using your formula ?

Comment: You can't convert mainnet current difficulty to stratum's 32 bits, it's too big. The current miner implementations, any hex string bigger than 4 bytes (8 chars) is treated directly as the target, no conversion. See the last paragraph of my answer.