# About shares in mining pool

Tags: mining-pools, difficulty-share, xmrig

I know that profits are assigned by the shares. But I want to know some details about computing the share.

For example, I get a job with difficulty 25000 to solve:

- Do I need to finish 25000 times of hash computing in a limited time to get a valid share?

or

- Is there a possibility that I just need to finish parts of the 25000 to get a valid share?
  In extreme cases, do I only need to calculate one hash to get a valid share?

This problem has bothered me for a long time. Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, not all shares are of equal value. A share with a difficulty of 25000 is worth more that a share with a difficulty of 250.

Second, it's worth understanding that difficulty (in PoW terms) is harder the *lower* the number, but in pools, will often be termed the other way round. I.e. they refer to the same thing but flipped around. With PoW you are trying to find a number *smaller* than another number. For example, with 0 being the hardest and 10 being the easiest, if you have a difficulty of 3, you are trying to find a number *smaller* than 3 (so 0, 1 or 2). With a difficulty of 3 (smallest hardest), you can flip that around to say *greater* than 7, and this is what you'll see with pools when referring to share difficulty. As 7 increases, the work is harder (and worth more), because you're ultimately trying to find a number smaller than max minus difficulty.

The hash function is just giving you a random number between 0 and 2^256-1. In the example above with 0 being hardest and 10 being easiest, that would be equivalent to a hash function returning a random number between 0 and 9.

> Do I need to finish 25000 times of hash computing in a limited time to get a valid share?

No, you do not need to hash 25000 times to solve a job with a difficulty (in pool terms) of 25000. You need to find a valid hash* within a certain amount of time. The pool will send you work based on how quickly you solved previous work so you end up submitting work at an approximate rate, typically ~30 seconds per job.

*Note that 25000 is only the top 32 bits of the actual difficulty number. See [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/11966/7493) which explains further.

> Is there a possibility that I just need to finish parts of the 25000 to get a valid share? In extreme cases, do I only need to calculate one hash to get a valid share?

You will on average find a valid hash (number) within the timeframe the pool targeted your job difficulty for. Sometimes it will take you longer, others less; extremes included.